# SPFx project compatible with spfx version 1.4.1

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, 2019

Is there anywhere project I can clone that has all correct dependencies to use with SPFx 1.4.1 version?

It's kind of urgent situation for me and everything I try just throws an error. Any help would be appreciated. I need it to be compatible with SharePoint 2019.

Comment: Why are you not starting from scratch? Use yeoman generator to create a new project and then use `npm install` to install all dependencies.

Comment: Do you need rest based project or no javascript framework  based?

Comment: @GaneshSanap react based project. I have many issues with versions so I wasn't able to create it on my own

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few SPFx web part samples which you can use to clone for SPFx web part development on SharePoint 2019 modern experience.

1. [Script editor web part for modern pages built in React](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor-onprem)
2. [Content Query Web Part (Compatible with On-Premises SharePoint versions)](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-content-query-onprem)
3. [Staff Directory (Search Directory) Version 2019](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-staff-directory-sp2019)
4. [List Items Menu (SP2019 Version)](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-list-items-menu-sp2019)
5. [Global News (SP2019 Version)](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-global-news-sp2019)
6. [Modern Experience Theme Manager](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/js-theme-manager-2019) - JavaScript based solution

---

Also, I will suggest you to check this Microsoft official documentation for using correct versions of all tools for SharePoint 2019 SPFx web parts development: [SharePoint Framework development tools and libraries compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)